# Can not get POST json value to a variable

Tags: angularjs

I have a function posts a value to a PHP file which seems to run fine until I get the response. PHP file returns the one row JSON response.

But I can not set it to a variable and use it as variablname[0], which seems to be the working in normal conditions.

Here's my code:

```
expoList.showdetail = function(expoID) {
          var detay;
          /*$scope.content = 'Please click the icons on the map for exposition event details. expoID=' + expoID;*/
          $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: base_url + '/Exposite_info_controller/get_expo_data',
                data: "expoID=" + expoID,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'}
          }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.expoList.detay = response.data;
          });
          var writehtml = '';
          writehtml += '<div id="info-image"><img src="images/expositions/' + detay[0].imagename + '" width="300" height="188" /></div>\r\n';
          writehtml += '<div id="address-info">'
          writehtml += '<strong>' + detay[0].expoName + '</strong><br />\r\n'
          writehtml += detay[0].expoAddress + '<br />\r\n';
          if(detay[0].expoAddress2 != '') {
              writehtml += detay[0].expoAddress2 + '<br />\r\n';
          }
          writehtml += detay[0].expoCity + '<br />\r\n';
          writehtml += '</div>\r\n';
          $scope.content = writehtml;
    };
```

And this is what returns from PHP file:

```
[{"expoID":"2","expoName":"CONGRESIUM ANKARA","expoAddress":"Sogutozu Caddesi No:1\/A, 06510 Cankaya","expoAddress2":"","expoCity":"Ankara","top":"150","left":"355","imagename":"congresiumankara.jpg","startdate":"2016-12-02","enddate":"2016-12-03"}]
```

I get the following error message from the console:

```
angular.min.js:122 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.expoList.showdetail (main.js:21)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:236), <anonymous>:4:300)
    at e (angular.min.js:281)
    at b.$eval (angular.min.js:147)
    at b.$apply (angular.min.js:147)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:281)
    at bg (angular.min.js:38)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.d (angular.min.js:38)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:122(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:94$apply @ angular.min.js:147(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:281bg @ angular.min.js:38d @ angular.min.js:38
```

Comment: Could you tell me what is the result if you use **typeof** with the response data? Try `typeof response` in the then callback function.

Comment: I haven't seen you filled your variable `detay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you get this error because the `detay` is not defined. Set the response as `detay = response.data;` instead.

Second, the $http returns a promise so put your code that supposed to act on the reponse inside of the then callback function like this

```
expoList.showdetail = function(expoID) {
          var detay;
          /*$scope.content = 'Please click the icons on the map for exposition event details. expoID=' + expoID;*/
          $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: base_url + '/Exposite_info_controller/get_expo_data',
                data: "expoID=" + expoID,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'}
          }).then(function(response) {
                detay = response.data;

                //Add code here

                  var writehtml = '';
                  writehtml += '<div id="info-image"><img src="images/expositions/' + detay[0].imagename + '" width="300" height="188" /></div>\r\n';
                  writehtml += '<div id="address-info">'
                  writehtml += '<strong>' + detay[0].expoName + '</strong><br />\r\n'
                  writehtml += detay[0].expoAddress + '<br />\r\n';
                  if(detay[0].expoAddress2 != '') {
                      writehtml += detay[0].expoAddress2 + '<br />\r\n';
                  }
                  writehtml += detay[0].expoCity + '<br />\r\n';
                  writehtml += '</div>\r\n';
                  $scope.content = writehtml;
          });

    };
```